# How is ParallelEnumerable.Zip() inteded to work, and why does the behavior change when calling AsEnumerable()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `ParallelEnumerable.Zip()` in conjunction with `IEnumerable<T>` and `AsEnumerable()`.

Given the code below the `parallelResult` and `result` will not be the same. Assuming `ParallelEnumerable.Zip()` mean that I just want to pair up items at random that makes sense. But if I uncomment `AsEnumerable()`, `parallelResult.ShouldBe(result)` no longer throws, even for very large `n` and repeated runs. If both inputs are `List`s the assertion also passes.

What's the expected behavior? Are we relying on an implementation detail when calling `AsEnumerable()`?

```
int n = 200;
IReadOnlyList<double> list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x=>(double)x).ToList();
IEnumerable<double> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(10, n).Select(x => (double)x);

var result = list
    .Zip(enumerable, Tuple.Create)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Item1)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Item2)
    .ToList();

var parallelResult = list
    .AsParallel()
    .Zip(enumerable.AsParallel(), Tuple.Create)
    // .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
    .ToList();

parallelResult.ShouldBe(result);
```

I've tried reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_ParallelEnumerable_Zip__3_System_Linq_ParallelQuery___0__System_Linq_ParallelQuery___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) but and [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs) but that doesn't make me wiser. Especially the source is hard to follow (which is expected with highly optimized parallel code).

Comment: Note that on my PC (Windows 10, 4.6.1), the test _sometimes_ passes even without uncommenting out that line. This essentially reinforces my point - the behaviour is not guaranteed to be in order, so don't rely on it to be (or not be).

Comment: @mjwills which framework version are you running? (I've tried on .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 4.6.2)

Comment: `I wonder why it behaves that way though.` The short answer is 'because the spec doesn't say it can't'. And whether it acts 100% consistently across runtimes, PCs etc - I very much doubt it.

Comment: For n=4: Shouldly.ShouldAssertException: parallelResult
    should be
[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13)]
    but was
[(0, 13), (1, 10), (2, 12), (3, 11)]
    difference
[*(0, 13)*, *(1, 10)*, (2, 12), *(3, 11)*]

Comment: Now admittedly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asenumerable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_ParallelEnumerable_AsEnumerable__1_System_Linq_ParallelQuery___0__ might imply that `AsEnumerable` should return them in order - due to `to force sequential evaluation of the query`. It depends if that is referring to the query **up to that point** (i.e. beforehand) or afterwards. I am not sure.

Comment: The [PLINQ Documentation on ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/order-preservation-in-plinq?view=netframework-4.7.2) explains some of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NetMage points out the [PLINQ documentation on ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/order-preservation-in-plinq?view=netframework-4.7.2#query-operators-and-ordering) states that `Zip()` is among the operators in the group "*The following PLINQ query operators may in some cases require ordered source sequences to produce correct results:*".

Hence `AsOrdered()` has to be used to guarantee that the same items are in each pair if the code is run multiple times. To get an ordered result the example above would have to look like this

```
int n = 200;
IReadOnlyList<double> list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x=>(double)x).ToList();
IEnumerable<double> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(10, n).Select(x => (double)x);

var result = list
    .Zip(enumerable, Tuple.Create)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Item1)
    .ThenBy(x=>x.Item2)
    .ToList();

var parallelResult = list
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Zip(enumerable.AsParallel().AsOrdered(), Tuple.Create)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Item2)
    .ToList();

parallelResult.ShouldBe(result);
```

All other cases of seemingly repeatable result is just coincidence, or due to implementation details that may change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an experimental attempt to understand the behavior of the [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.zip) PLINQ operator. Two [`ParallelQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1)s that include a bit of processing (simulated with `Thread.Sleep`) are zipped, and the zipping itself includes a bit of processing too:

```
ParallelQuery<string> source1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).AsParallel().Select(n =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(200); Print($"Producing: A{n}"); return $"A{n}";
});

ParallelQuery<string> source2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().Select(n =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); Print($"Producing: B{n}"); return $"B{n}";
});

(string, string)[] result = source1.Zip(source2, (x, y) =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Print($"Zipping: {x} + {y}");
    return (x, y);
}).ToArray();

Print($"Result: {String.Join(", ", result)}");

static void Print(object value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Thread.CurrentThread
        .ManagedThreadId}] > {value}");
}
```

Output:

```
20:20:48.210 [1] > Producing: A1
20:20:48.334 [1] > Producing: B1
20:20:48.434 [1] > Zipping: A1 + B1
20:20:48.635 [1] > Producing: A2
20:20:48.736 [1] > Producing: B2
20:20:48.836 [1] > Zipping: A2 + B2
20:20:49.036 [1] > Producing: A3
20:20:49.136 [1] > Producing: B3
20:20:49.237 [1] > Zipping: A3 + B3
20:20:49.437 [1] > Producing: A4
20:20:49.537 [1] > Producing: B4
20:20:49.637 [1] > Zipping: A4 + B4
20:20:49.838 [1] > Producing: A5
20:20:49.938 [1] > Producing: B5
20:20:50.038 [1] > Zipping: A5 + B5
20:20:50.043 [1] > Result: (A1, B1), (A2, B2), (A3, B3), (A4, B4), (A5, B5)
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BhIVVe).

Everything is running sequentially on the current thread (the thread with ID #1). No parallelization is taking place. That was not the behavior that I expected to see.