# Parallel with Zip lists in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, parallel.foreachasync

I have a code in async that looks like this:

```
List<Task<(decimal, decimal)?>> tasks = offsets
    .Zip(prices, async (offset, price) => await Func(offset, price));

(decimal, decimal)?[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

And I would like to use `Parallel` instead.
but

```
ParallelLoopResult result1 = Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    offsets.Zip(prices, (offset, price) => await Func(offset, price));
```

does not work as foreach takes only 1 argument.
Any idea how I could do that please?

Comment: Your first example doesn't even compile as you're trying to use `await` in a non-async delegate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is ParallelEnumerable.Zip() inteded to work, and why does the behavior change when calling AsEnumerable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519576/how-is-parallelenumerable-zip-inteded-to-work-and-why-does-the-behavior-chang)

Comment: I forgot the async. Now it compiles. And not really, I dont properly understand the example

Comment: It's not an either or proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should compile:

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 // Configurable
};

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(offsets.Zip(prices), parallelOptions, async (pair, ct) =>
{
    var (offset, price) = pair;
    await Func(offset, price);
});
```

It uses this [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) overload:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body);
```